# Pip not using shims, but system 'pip' for pyenv

Tags: python, pip, pyenv, apple-m1

I'm facing an issue with getting the right 'pip' in my pyenv environment. I've tried reinstalling pyenv, but the issue persists. I'm on a MacBook Air, with the M1 chip. I'm essentially trying to keep pip and site-packages separate for my Python 3.9.4 install, but somehow it keeps referencing the 'pip' that is system-wide.

Current versions:

```
<me>:~:$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /Users/<me>/.pyenv/version)
  3.9.4
```

At my $HOME prompt:

```
<me>:~:$ python -V
Python 2.7.16
<me>:~:$ which pip
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip
<me>:~:$ pip -V
pip 21.1 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Within <project 1>, I have a .python_version file which is for 3.9.4

```
<me>:~:$ cd ~//<project 1>/
<me>:~//<project 1>:$ python -V
Python 3.9.4
<me>:~//<project 1>:$ pyenv versions
  system
* 3.9.4 (set by /Users/<me>/<project 1>/.python-version)
```

However, when I do a "which pip" or a "pip -V" it shows the system pip binary:

```
<me>:~/<project 1>:$ which pip
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip

<me>:~//<project 1>:$ pip -V
pip 21.1 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Any thoughts on how to get this working with the 'pip' under the pyenv version?

Comment: Comparing a Linux install vs. the above Mac install, I realize that in the .pyenv/shims directory, the Mac build is missing pip, pip3, and pip3.9. Not sure why.

Comment: Uninstalled pyenv, and tried installing it through homebrew. Install worked, but same issue as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the root of the issue was that in the shims folder, no pip files were being installed.

When I replayed the install process a few times, I noticed that in the final install steps, I was seeing the following logged output:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (21.1)
```

I ended up deleting all existing pip installs on my machine (both in opt/homebrew/ and in $HOME/.local/lib/python*). When I tried reinstalling, I then got the following:

```
    * WARNING: The scripts pip3 and pip3.9 are installed in '/$HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/bin' which is not on PATH.
    * Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
    * Successfully installed pip-20.2.3 setuptools-49.2.1
```

As suggested above, added the following snippet to my bash_profile file:

```sh
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/versions/:$PATH"
```

**This could probably be avoided if the pyenv installer just ignored existing installs and went ahead with ensuring pip is installed in the shims folder.**

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, fixed it by adding the following to my `.zshrc` (replacing `<username>`), adapted from [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1342)

```
# pyenv
export PATH="/Users/<username>/.pyenv/shims:$PATH"
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
```

Note: all installs were done via `Brew`